# Unable to debug flask application in Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: python, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code

I'm having some trouble debugging a flask application in Visual Studio Code.

I have configured my launch settings for a flask application, and I'm running a Python 3.6 virtual environment when working locally.

I want to be able to live watch variables etc, so was hoping it would be fairly simple to do, but for some reason, when I press the "Run and Debug" button, my flask app fails to run with the following error:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\StoreServicesStoreBuilder\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder> ${env:PTVSD_LAUNCHER_PORT}='55000'; & 'c:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\StoreServicesStoreBuilder\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder\.venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\jmatson\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\new_ptvsd\no_wheels\ptvsd\launcher' '-m' 'flask' 'run' '--no-debugger' '--port' '5000'
 * Serving Flask app "C:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\StoreServicesStoreBuilder/StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder/app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder.app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\StoreServicesStoreBuilder\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py",
line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\StoreServicesStoreBuilder\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from model import Page, ActivityTask, ActivityTemplate, TemplateActivityTask, Server, ProgressBar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

This error is despite the application running fine when I simply use 'python app.py'. Here is my import code for app.py (model is a local module, so just another .py file saved in the same directory as app.py)

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, flash, Response
import logging
import json
import requests
import os
from model import Page, ActivityTask, ActivityTemplate, TemplateActivityTask, Server, ProgressBar
from operations import ApiOperation, InSiteAPI, Helpers
from config import Config
import forms
from forms import ActivityTaskForm, SubmitDeleteActivityForm, ActivityTemplateForm, ActivityTemplateUpdateForm
from dbmodel import DbActivityTask, DbActivityTemplate, DbTemplateActivityTask
from pynamodb.models import Model
from pynamodb.attributes import (
    UnicodeAttribute, NumberAttribute, UnicodeSetAttribute, UTCDateTimeAttribute
)
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       19/02/2020   2:49 PM                .venv
d-----        1/02/2020   2:16 PM                infrastructure
d-----        1/02/2020   2:16 PM                local_deployment
d-----        1/02/2020   2:16 PM                static
d-----       28/02/2020  12:38 PM                templates
d-----        6/03/2020   4:28 PM                __pycache__
-a----        3/03/2020   2:30 PM             96 .gitignore
-a----        6/03/2020   4:25 PM           9106 app.py
-a----        1/02/2020   4:23 PM            370 config.py
-a----        6/03/2020   9:29 AM           2784 dbmodel.py
-a----       19/02/2020   2:45 PM           1951 dbmodel.pyc
-a----        5/03/2020   1:30 PM           2594 forms.py
-a----        6/03/2020   3:25 PM           9275 model.py
-a----       19/02/2020   2:45 PM           2969 model.pyc
-a----       19/02/2020   2:45 PM           1239 operations.py
-a----        6/03/2020   8:49 AM           3549 README.md
-a----        1/02/2020   2:19 PM           1324 requirements.txt
-a----        1/02/2020   2:16 PM            213 zappa_settings.json
-a----        1/02/2020   2:16 PM              0 __init__.py
```

Here is how I've tried configuring my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder/app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload",
                "--port",
                "5000"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Unsure if this is relevant or not, but this is how I've set my python path and linting path:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}\\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder\\.venv\\scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "${workspaceRoot}\\StoreServices-Flask-StoreBuilder\\.venv\\scripts\\pylint.exe",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true
}
```

EDIT: Note - I have also ensured I am selecting the correct Interpreter in VS Code - Python 3.6.6 from my .venv environment. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do note that `python app.py` is not the same as `python -m flask run` which is how you have configured the debugger to execute your app. Try either making it work the same way the debugger is launching it or change your `launch.json` to match how you are manually running it.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for your comments - how would I change launch.json to run python app.py? I am following a template for the settings I have so not sure what I'd need to change. Can you assist?

Comment: You're basically after the "current file" configuration template, but with what file to run hard-coded to `${workspaceFolder}/app.py`. If you look at the [debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and specifically the [`startup.py` example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options) you will have an example to work from.